# При добавление дня к текущей дате некорректно работает если это последний день месяца

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой что при добавлении блока я создаю календать, и должен в него записать завтрашнею дату, проблема что если сегодня 31 число и 7 месяц, то при добалнению +1 день должно посчитать 01.08, но сейчас после добавления выдаёт 32.07. Буду признателен за помощь, если подскажите как правильно сделать.

```
addDayOff() {
            let nowDate = new Date();
            let date = nowDate.getDate() + 1;
            let month = nowDate.getMonth() + 1;
            let year = nowDate.getFullYear();

            if (date <= 9) date = `0${date}`;
            if (month <= 9) month = `0${month}`;

            this.calendar.unshift({
                startDate: `${year}-${month}-${date}`,
                endDate: `${year}-${month}-${date}`,
                onGoingStartDate: `${month}-${date}`,
                onGoingEndDate: `${month}-${date}`,
                startTime: this.ruleData.startTime,
                endTime: this.ruleData.endTime,
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
addDayOff() {
        let nowDate = new Date(Date.now() + 24*60*60*1000);
        let date = nowDate.getDate() ;
        let month = nowDate.getMonth() + 1;
        let year = nowDate.getFullYear();

        if (date <= 9) date = `0${date}`;
        if (month <= 9) month = `0${month}`;

        this.calendar.unshift({
            startDate: `${year}-${month}-${date}`,
            endDate: `${year}-${month}-${date}`,
            onGoingStartDate: `${month}-${date}`,
            onGoingEndDate: `${month}-${date}`,
            startTime: this.ruleData.startTime,
            endTime: this.ruleData.endTime,
        });
    },
```

Значение, возвращённое методом `getDate()`, является целым числом от 1 до 31.

Метод [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) возвращает месяц указанной даты по местному времени, нумерация месяцев начинается с нуля для первого месяца в году, то есть от 0 до 11

Метод `getYear()` возвращает год минус 1900

Вам нужно быть аккуратным с месяцами

Comment: Дни с вашим кодом правильно считает а месяц остаёться прежний, тоесть если сейчас 31.07 - то результат получаеться 01.07

Comment: Странно я добавил один день к текущему

Comment: если сделать так let month = nowDate.getMonth() + 1 то в принцыпе вроде как правильно теперь всё работает

Comment: Ясно дайте 10 мин

Comment: но наверно с таким кодом let month = nowDate.getMonth() + 1 будет такаяже проблема как и с днями, что когда будет последний месяц 12 то оно сделает 13 вместо того чтобы перейти на следующий год

Comment: а так лучше, с дополнениями?

Comment: да, дни правильно считает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111278/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and-dimafront).